# How to make a difference between month 1 and 10 in my data set?

Tags: r, reshape, rda

This is part of my code.

```
library(reshape2)
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/WildFires/FedFire8004/FedFire8004")
load("fedfire8004.rda")
library(reshape2)
Acres <- melt(fedfire8004$acres)
```

It reads data which has lat,lon,time(monthly) and value and converts data to below format(Acres). The problem is that in output there is no difference between month 1 and month 10. They both are stored under for example 1983.10 for month 1 and 10 of 1980.Is it possible that I store them in different format like 1980.1 and 1980.10 for month 1 and 10.

```
     lat  lon  month      Acre
1  -118.5 48.5 1983.10    1692.9
2  -117.5 48.5 1983.10      11.1
3  -116.5 48.5 1983.10       0.0
4  -115.5 48.5 1983.10       1.1
5  -114.5 48.5 1983.10       0.0
6  -113.5 48.5 1983.10     151.2
7  -112.5 48.5 1983.10       5.0
```

Comment: If `class(fedfire8004$month)`is `numeric`, then it is too late. You will have to go back to a file or a previous R data that allows to distinguish between january and october. You'll want to split year and month into two different columns or store yyyy.mm as a `character`. You could also replace the `.` with a \ to avoid numeric interpretation.

Comment: @flodel; no the class is "integer".

Comment: can you please show `str(fedfire8004$acres)`?

Comment: @flodel;num [1:24, 1:18, 1:300] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
     ..$ lon  : chr [1:24] "-124.5" "-123.5" "-122.5" "-121.5" ...
     ..$ lat  : chr [1:18] "31.5" "32.5" "33.5" "34.5" ...
     ..$ month: chr [1:300] "1980.1" "1980.2" "1980.3" "1980.4" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from `melt` applying `type.convert` to the dim names of your data. To avoid character to numeric conversion, you can replace the `.` by a `-`. Try:

```
dimnames(fedfire8004$acres)$month <- sub("\\.", "-",
                                         dimnames(fedfire8004$acres)$month)
```

Then apply `melt` again and you should see `1980-1` and `1980-10`.

Comment: Nicely assessed. I think `melt` is being too "aggressive" in its efforts at DWIM-ing if it is automatically coercing dimension attribute types.